# T-SQL select query row numbers as they were without WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

Example table produced by

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by color) as row, 
    color 
from color_table
```

Output:

```
row color
----------
1   black
2   blue
3   cyan
4   yellow
```

Then I want to exclude some rows using eg. `WHERE color<>"blue"` but row should remain the same.

Resulting table should be

```
row color
---------
1   black
3   cyan
4   yellow
```

How to write this query? Table is rather big so query should be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it in a subquery and filter the result outside.

```
SELECT *
FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by color) as row, color from color_table) a
WHERE color != 'blue'
```

Comment: My real query is rather complicated and table has 50k+ rows, how efficient would it be?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CTE to simplify the logic.

```
;WITH Numbered_clor_table
AS
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by color) as row, color from color_table
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbered_clor_table
WHERE color != 'blue'
```